# local issuer certificate error uniquely in docker with python

Tags: python, docker, ssl, url, ssl-certificate

Following error occurs only with docker app in python when making request to an https url.

`<urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1108)>`

Outside of docker, the app works. I can fetch the same URL inside the docker image of other language app such as dotnet.

I have tried:

1. `RUN update-ca-certificates`
2. Install `certfi` library and manually supply the certificates during making the call
3. Manually insert the certificates that comes with `certify` library in different locations of docker images such as `/usr/local/share/ca-certificates/`, `/etc/ssl/certs/` and `RUN update-ca-certificates`
4. Tried different versions (`3.6.9`, `3.8.4`) and providers (`alpine`, `buster`, `slim-buster` ) of python.
5. Setting different env variables such as `REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE`, `SSL_CERT_FILE` etc.
6. Use different libraries such as `requests`, `urllib`, `urllib3`

.... and really large number of different things.

It of course works when I turn the verify off, but I want to keep verification.

Answer (score 6):

I was having this issue in an ARM Ubuntu 20.04 container.

I installed ca-certificates and curl, but I still couldn't use curl. For me the fix ended up being adding the following before calling curl:

```
export SSL_CERT_FILE=/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
```

Comment: It helps me for composer on alpine docker image

Comment: Yes! Thank you! This did the trick!! I hit this trying to use `curl` on `balenalib/rpi-raspbian:buster`. Don't even need to `RUN update-ca-certificates` anymore.

Comment: I was having the same issue with the `python:3.8-slim` image. This works like a charm, thanks a lot!

Comment: This did not help me on python:39-bullseye unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

If you are using tornado.httpclient.HTTPRequest setting the options ca_certs may produce this result despite the fact that the ca_cert file in use is supposed to define the parent of the pem file supplied by another party with a key file.
This appears to be a result from overriding the default that likely points to a directory containing needed cert files. In some cases it can works to omit the ca_cert parameter and ignore included ca_certs.
Curl and even ssl.wrap_socket over socket may still work with the same exact parameters but tornado.httpclient.HTTPRequest does not.
The real issue here is that many libs don't have the ability to tell you what certificates are being considered and why, and which certificates are missing.

Answer (score 0):

I was having this with openai from langchain running a docker container on a work laptop protected by zscaler. In the end, a combination of @SimonBiggs answer and [this other one worked](https://community.openai.com/t/ssl-certificate-verify-failed/32442/39): I concatenated the ca-certificates.crt from the container with the ZScaler one I added myself from my browser.

Details:

I created a local directory resources/certs and stored my ZscalerRootCA.cer cert there from this procedure from OpenAPI community: https://community.openai.com/t/ssl-certificate-verify-failed/32442/39

Then I copied that and concatenated it with the ca-certificates

```
COPY resources/ resources/
RUN cat resources/certs/ZscalerRootCA.cer /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt > resources/certs/certs.crt
```

My python file now has this:

```py
CERTS = "/home/app_user/resources/certs/certs.crt"
if os.path.exists(CERTS):
    print(f"Setting certificate from: {CERTS}")
    os.environ["REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE"] = CERTS
```

making it conditional allows it to run locally as well as in the docker container.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Rhubarb answer, if you are getting an error while building your docker image you can append the ZscalerRootCA.crt at the end of your container`s crt file.

For nodejs18 ubi8 docker image, you can follow Rhubarb`s step 1 and then use this command in the docker file:

```
COPY resources/ resources/
RUN cat resources/certs/ZscalerRootCA.crt >> /etc/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt
```